# VB6 data report: "Failed getting Rowset(s) from current data source"

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, reporting

I've been following the procedures at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262325(v=vs.60).aspx) for several hours and I can't seem to make it work on my project. Simple reports are working, but when I use the parent-child stuff or grouping, the error "Failed getting Rowset(s) from current data source" always occurs.

I have two tables:

1. tblItems
2. tblItemCategory

I need a column from tblItemCategory so I came up with this SQL query:

```
SELECT ic.Code AS 'Category Code'
     , ic.Description AS 'Category'
     , i.ItemCode AS 'Item Code'
     , i.Description 
FROM   dbo.tblItems i
INNER JOIN 
       tblItemCategory ic
ON     i.ItemCategory=ic.Code
```

This query is **working** if I only show the records the usual manner in the Data Report (Page Header-Details manner). When I use grouping,

[image]

it becomes like this:

[image]

Therefore, I just dragged the Summary fields to the Group section and the Detail fields to the Detail section.

[image]

This does not work.

[image]

I tried using the Northwind Access database and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason why it works on Access but not in SQL Server is that:

Access: Use client-side cursors

SQL Server: Use server-side cursors